# Angular: How to set baseHref for assets in development when using SSR

Tags: angular, angular-routing, assets

In production we are setting the base href with:

```
ng build --base-href /app/
```

This works well. Especially our assets are also served at `/app/assets/` as expected.

I cannot achieve the same effect **in development** however, where we run:

```
ng run project:serve-ssr
```

Assets remain at `/assets` and are not accessible at `/app/assets`.

Things I have tried in `angular.json`

- setting `architect.build.options.baseHref`
- setting `architect.serve.options.servePath`
- setting `architect.server.options.servePath` (not allowed)
- setting `architect.serve-ssr.options.servePath` (not allowed)

I have also tried to set the DI token `APP_BASE_HREF` and provide it in the AppModue, but to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [@nguniversal](https://github.com/angular/universal) we solved this by creating a virtual path prefix in `server.ts`:

```js
server.use(process.emv.BASE_HREF, express.static(distFolder));
```

The `BASE_HREF` is set as an environment variable during app start:

```js
BASE_HREF=/app ng run project:serve-ssr
```

Comment: This seems like the better solution.

Comment: At least it worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up, rewriting the url in the express server in development. Not super happy with that though, so if anybody has a better answer, I will happily accept that.

In `server.ts`:

```js
if (environment.removeAssetsPrefix.length) {
  server.use((req, _, next) => {
    if (req.url.startsWith(environment.removeAssetsPrefix + '/assets/')) {
      req.url = req.url.substring(environment.removeAssetsPrefix.length);
    }
    next();
  });
}
```

In `environment.ts`:

```js
export const environment = { 
  ...
  removeAssetsPrefix: '/app'
};
```